# Numpy - Circular indexing by skip

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a `np.arange()` array of arbitrary length, `x = np.arange(10)` for example, what is an efficient way to generate an output array that skips every `n` values starting from `0` up to `n`?

Sample code with current method and output:

```py
def circ(arr, n):
    y = np.array([])
    for i in range(n):
        y = np.concatenate((y, arr[i::n]))
    return y.astype(int)

for i in range(1,6):
    circ(x, i)

"""
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
array([0, 3, 6, 9, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8])
array([0, 4, 8, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 3, 7])
array([0, 5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9])
"""
```

It would be easy to just use mod, but note that with case `4` that once the list exhausts all the ways to accumulate 3 elements by skipping every 4, it accumulates 2 elements.

I considered a sort of pad, resize, flatten, and discard type, but I'm not sure of a good way to discard the padded values in the end:

```py
def circ2(arr, n):
    arr2 = np.zeros(n*math.ceil(len(arr)/n))
    arr2[:len(arr)] = arr
    arr3 = np.resize(arr2, (len(arr2)//n, n))
    return arr3.T.ravel()

for i in range(1,5):
    circ2(x, i)

"""
array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
array([0., 2., 4., 6., 8., 1., 3., 5., 7., 9.])
array([0., 3., 6., 9., 1., 4., 7., 0., 2., 5., 8., 0.])
array([0., 4., 8., 1., 5., 9., 2., 6., 0., 3., 7., 0.])
"""
```

The for loop method works, but it will be really inefficient for larger arrays (up to 5000 elements). Does anyone know of a function, or have insights on making this faster, or a different method?

Answer (score 1):

Repeated concatenation is inefficient as you have to create a new array over and over.

A loop with a single concatenation should be more efficient:

```
x = np.arange(10)
n = 4

out = np.concatenate([x[i::n] for i in range(n)])
```

Output:

```
array([0, 4, 8, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 3, 7])
```

As a function:

```
def circ2(arr, n):
    return np.concatenate([arr[i::n] for i in range(n)])
```

Timings for a loop of `n in range(1, 6)` on an input array of 1M items:

```
# your approach
110 ms ± 4.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# the single concatenate
17.7 ms ± 540 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```